# How to calculate number of simple graphs with 6 vertices if all of vertices have a even degree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Hello guys i have an important question, i know how to calculate number of simple graphs based on their edges but here situation is different . In the question every vertex have a even degree so in my opinion it means we can only have degree of 0 , degree of 2 and degree of 4 for each one of vertices.

What is your suggestion ?

do you know any formula for that?

Comment: My suggestion is case work.

Comment: @saulspatz so you mean we should take every possibility under consideration!

Comment: What about P.I.E?